# How do I hide scriptlet code from a regular web browser. eg. combine <!-- and <%

Tags: html, jsp, comments, scriptlet

Is there a way to hide scriptlet code from a regular web browser?  I want to have my jsp so you could just drag and drop it onto a web browser and it would sort of work and not show the scriptlet code as part of the output.

I know I can do this, and the java code still works properly, but doesn't show up in the web browser

`<!--
<% // some scriptlet code %>
-->`

But I'm wondering if there is a way to combine these together.  something like:
`<!--%  %-->`.    Am I just missing something?

NOTE: I know that if you were to serve this on a proper JSP server the scriptlet wouldn't appear. I'm just talking about if you were to not serve it anywhere, just drop it into a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the scriptlet code output to be displayed if the JSP page is run, but you don't what the scriptlet code to be displayed if the page is served as simple HTML. Is that correct?

This is a bit contrived, but you could do:

`<!--<%="-"+"->"%><% some scriptlet code %><%="<!-"+"-"%>-->`